# PHP script to detect Chrome browser version

Tags: php, user-agent

Is there a way to detect Chrome browser version using PHP?
Basically, I'm looking for a way to detect:

```
if Chrome version 101 and below
```

and

```
if Chrome version 102 and above.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Right now I have the basics:

```
function get_browser_name($user_agent){
    if (strpos($user_agent, 'Chrome')) return 'Chrome';
    return 'Other';
}

    if (get_browser_name($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) == "Chrome") 
    {
        echo "something here";
    }
    
    else {};
```

Comment: You have to look at the user agents these different browsers send by default, and see if there is a difference to exploit. Have you looked?

Comment: But also...why do you want to do this? Really, your backed code should not have to care if the request is coming from browser X, browser Y, an IOT device, a Postman test, a VR headset, a smart fridge, or whatever. What problem are you trying to solve with this idea? I woud guess it's potentially a workaround for some other issue which you would be better to solve directly.

Comment: Google has the de-facto monopoly so other browsers often need to disguise themselves as Chrome. Unless you're trying to work around a bug in one specific Chrome version that doesn't affect other Chromium-based browsers, browser detection is not likely to work for you.

Comment: PHP should not know about that at all. It serves the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This is **NOT** recommended.

There are a myriad of reasons, but the short answer is that the Browser version is a Client Side concept and should not be relevant to the Server as this can get in the way of various server-side concerns (most notably Caching).

I've made this mistake in the past, and it led to the server caching the response of a user with an unsupported browser version and sending out the cached response to users with a valid browser.

Instead, you should probably look into [parsing the User Agent with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser) and modifying your behavior based on your versioning criteria.

My guess is that you're probably attempting to render out a browser compatibility notification of some kind, which can be done with a combination of server-side templating and client-side detection.

[Many answers on SO touch on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137200/how-to-redirect-my-page-based-on-the-browsers-the-user-uses) so definitely check them out.

Comment: Ya. Basically Chrome versions 102 and up have their "Download" notifications on top bar, while those with versions 101 and under have their "Download" notifications on the bottom left. I usually pop a message on the website notifying users where to find their downloads, but now with the latest versions, it screws up everything. Trying to find a way to detect version and give users a message based on that version.

Comment: @BeePollen that would be something you could do in JavaScript a bit more reliably and easily. But really it's not your job to teach users how to use their browser!!

Answer (score 0):

The server should not be aware of that. You may parse on client side with the help of the `navigator` object in javascript.

```
navigator.appVersion
```

for example will give you a string as

```
5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

In this simple case of Chrome, you can use a regex to extract the version.

```
navigator.appVersion.match(/Chrome\/(\d+)/)[1]
```

gives you the `115`.

The user agent may be hidden or different to `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` if a firewall or anti-virus blocks it or even a proxy change it. In that case you could post it from JS via AJAX.

**But all this is not recommended.**

Just output your HTML server side. If you need to know an explicit feature is supported by a special version, check [can i use](https://caniuse.com/) for compatibility.